# A collection of template objects with different template parameters

Tags: c++, templates, stl

As a kind of factory-method setup I want to register functors which each create objects of a different type, but meet a common interface - i.e all create objects subclassing a core class.

Say I have something like:

```
template <class T> struct FactoryMethod
{
 X* create();
}
```

I cannot have (IIRC) `std::map<std::string,FactoryMethod*>` because each `FactoryMethod` template specialization is a separate type. But I *could* do:

```
struct IFactoryMethod
{
 virtual X* create()=0;
};
template <class T> struct FactoryMethod : public IFactoryMethod
{
 virtual X* create();
};
std::map<std::string,IFactoryMethod*> factories;
```

Right? I am not aware standard STL has a way to make this neater though I guess boost does - however we don't use boost right now and I am interested anyway.

The idea is then `factories` can be looked up based on type-name (read from XML for instance) to create the right type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is known as type erasure and is a fairly common idiom- although your map could of course be made of ownership-enforcing pointers and you could also use a virtual destructor like most sane people.

Comment: it's pseudo code, give me a break! Although can you clarify "ownership-enforcing pointers"?

Comment: He's basically telling you to NOT use raw pointer, instead, you could use shared_ptr<IFactoryMethod> or unique_ptr<IFactoryMethod> which makes working with pointers safe. They come from boost, you can also find them in std::tr1 or std in c++0x. You can take a look here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/doc/html/boost/interprocess/unique_ptr.html

Comment: No, they're smart enough to use the alternatives, which are far superior :P

Comment: I never found a "best" smart-ptr, they all seem to have caveats. I rarely see experienced C++ people make elementary pointer mistakes.